# Could this bounty be left open forever?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, asking-questions

I opened [this bounty](https://superuser.com/questions/710495/is-it-possible-to-run-corona-sdk-on-reactos-or-wine), no answers yet and probably no solutions will be given any time soon, because I really asked a hard, maybe impossible question. I know that and that's why I opened a bounty.

The problem itself is solved, I got a windows XP image, but I would like to know the answer to my question. I don't want that the bounty goes for nothing. I am not asking for a refund and I am aware that this is an impossible thing, probably.

All I want is for my bounty to be open forever. Maybe two years from now there will be a solution. Maybe they'll create a Corona that runs on Wine or natively on Linux. Then someone would answer my question and I'll be giving him the bounty. That way I get my answer, he gets his bounty and we're both happy.

If it goes to nothing, no one wins. I don't get my answer, I lose rep, and the problem is not solved.

Comment: Bounties **draw attention**; not answers. Your question got the attention, when the bounty expires it is the turn of other questions to get attention. What makes your question so special to allow it to hog the limelight?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes and maybe 2 years from now, it will draw the attention of someone who deserve the bounty. if it goes now, no one wins

Comment: If a bounty could be open forever there becomes little point in having  the system...

Comment: And maybe the question will be answered anyway in two years, even without the bounty.  Or, you could do us the courtesy of self-posting an answer if you find out from Corona how to do it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey maybe, but the moment I opened the bounty, I lost rep, why wasting it for nothing? why not giving it to that someone who answers it?

Comment: @Fischer: you didn't waste it, the question drew attention. If you expected it to draw answers instead, then that was the wrong expectation, sorry.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards no, since if there's an answer with minimum 2 upvotes, he'll be rewarded the bounty even if i didn't give it to him

Comment: @Fischer: the answer would gain *half* the bounty.

Comment: @MartijnPieters still better than being wasted to nothingness

Comment: That isn't really an answer to my point @Fischer... you're asking for a bounty to be open forever, and I'm saying you might just as well scrap bounties if that happens.

Comment: @Fischer: Bounties are like an advertisement budget. You got your advertisement slot, and like all marketing campaigns, there is a chance people don't buy the product. But you still got access to the rare commodity: attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i don't need the advertisement no more, i got a solution, being on the featured page means nothing to me, but awarding it to someone is better than nothingness, by philosophical definition, anything is better than nothing

Comment: If that is all that important to you, nothing stops you from offering a bounty time and time again. The value will double up to 500 max each time, so it's going to cost you. But that's the price you'll have to pay.

Comment: @Fischer: then don't use a bounty like that. You can add a bounty after the fact to award to an existing answer.

Comment: @Bart think about the rep as your money, they cant disapear, if you cant get it back, someone should get get them, nothingness is the worst option

Comment: Advertisements don't guarantee responses. Nor do bounties. That's a fact you'll have to live with. At most you can do what @MartijnPieters says; award a bounty to an existing answer once you get one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and would you spend 100k on a car that you know you can buy for 12k?

Comment: @Fischer: of course not; but you are not buying answers here. You are the car salesman hoping to *sell* the car, and are drawing in punters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bounties are meant to **feature** questions.  The ability to feature a question is contingent on the ability to do it within a limited time window.  Otherwise, bountied questions would pile up over time, and *none* of them would get any special attention.

Comment: then why not change the system a bit? bounties which are not answered within the time window are removed from the featured page, but they are awarded if someone answers them

Comment: @Fischer: again, that's not the goal of a bounty. It is a side-effect of the current system; an extra incentive to answer *in a limited time frame*. But the votes and the accept mark are still there; just like limited-time offers, you can still have the product, just not at the reduced rate.

Comment: Answers diminish in value and importance the longer the time elapses between the question and answer.

Comment: @Fischer: And if we allow bounties to persist we'd devalue all unanswered questions that never had a bounty.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, if the asker thinks that his question is really valuable to him, better open a bounty, I don't see why you open a bounty if you think that your question is not important

Comment: @RobertHarvey i know but anything is better than nothingness in my humble opinion

Comment: @Fischer: of course the question asker thinks the question is important; that's why you pay a bounty to draw attention. It is the *expectation of an answer* that is incorrect here. On Stack Exchange sites, the offers on sale really are limited.

Answer (score 7):

Bounties have been created to highlight questions and draw attention to them for a **little time**. If a bounty becomes endless, spotlights of featured questions would be useless, because flooded in old questions...

[Look at StackOverflow,](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) there's already 426 questions featured at the moment (16/02/2014 midnight UTC). Imagine if every old unanswered questions with bounties were kept... :-)

Comment: read my comment @robert